# how to insert variables of type dictionary in database

Tags: c#, sql, dictionary

I want to insert some values of type   `var dict = new Dictionary<string, int>();`.I have 4 loop and i want to insert another values beside the variables of **var dict**
here is my code

```
 var dict = new Dictionary<string, int>();
                    foreach (string word in wordsbeforesoundex)
                    {

                        if (word == null)
                        {
                            continue;
                        }
                        if (word.Trim() != "")
                        {
                            if (dict.ContainsKey(word))
                            {
                                dict[word]++;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                dict[word] = 1;
                            }
                        }

                    }
    for (int l = 0; l < words.Length; l++)
    {
        con.Open();

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO TableFFF (Frequency) VALUES (@dict_idx)", con);


        cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@dict_idx", dict[wordsbeforesoundex[l]]));


        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close();
    }
```

My problem is how to fetch the data in the dictionary and insert it in the database

Comment: Would it be possible for you to rephrase the question I cannot make any sense of it. If you want to search for a Key in a dictionary you can do that using the dict.Keys property.

Comment: Are you looking for `dict.Keys`?

Comment: My magic crystall ball says : _"Use a class with 4 properties as value"_.

Comment: I have updated my question,i hope it's more clear now

Answer (score 0):

You will need to have two columns, one for the dictionary key (word) and another for the dictionary value (frequency)

```
foreach(var pair in dict)
{
    con.Open();

    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO TableFFF (Word, Frequency) VALUES (@word, @freq)", con);

    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@word", pair.Key);
    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@freq", pair.Value);

    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    con.Close();
}
```

Comment: can i use for instead of foreach??

Comment: i have tried this but i got that error No mapping exists from object type System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2+KeyCollection[[System.String, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089],[System.Int32, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]] to a known managed provider native type.

Comment: It seems you are trying to put the `pair` as a parameter instead o `pair.Key` and `pair.Value`. I've fixed my answer because it has a typo in the parameters (it said dict instead of pair)

Answer (score -1):

You NEEd TO USE FOR loop instead of foreach.. to pass the right values you will need for loop and change the pair.key to pair[for loop index].key

```
using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO TableFFF (Word, Frequency) VALUES (@word, @freq)", con))
{
    con.Open();
    for (int i = 0; i < dict.Count; i++)
   {   
      cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@word", pair[i].Key);
      cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@freq", pair[i].Value);

      cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

    }
}
```

with **using**,  connection will dispose after finished automatically

Comment: Not actually. And also, how this is an answer?

Comment: @ivowiblo when i gave this answer i don't know why but i couldn' t see **add comment** button.. i forgot to write this situation in my answer..wrote some other places but here i forgot.. so i would need to write it as an answer :(

And about the for loop.. as you know better than me the for loop has more performance than foreach loop ;)

Comment: so if the user who asks help, **we** need to give the better ;) which they can do the examples correctly..

he asked that "can i use for loop instead of foreach?" and got error..

so this means for loop is better (simply) for him..

and if a user's answer solves his problem this would be **the answer**

Comment: But he DOESN'T NEED to use the for instead the foreach. the problem he was having was different! Indeed, it seems you just copied from another answer and forgot to add stuff, like where did that `pair` variable come from? The answer to "can i use for loop instead of foreach?" is "Yes" and that's it, but it wasn't the question, it was just a question.

Comment: if he understand and do it correctly and faster then he need do this way..

You can't wait that everyone follows your way.. Someone uses for loop someone foreach, and someone prefers another way..

about the copying from another answer..

firstly, i didn't want to break your answer from a little dict.key fault

in that why i just tried to simply send him to way which he can understand eaiser (to for loop) and where he need to change in his for loop..

and as you seen it before, my answer didn't give error ;)

so this can be a proof which is copied from another, ha ?

Comment: of course it gives error, `pair` doesn't exist! and you didn't say "if you want to use for, here's an example". you said "you NEED to use for" and that's wrong.

Comment: this is not about only for-foreach loop.. this is about thinking style..

if we help to someone and the ones who we try to help need to another way of coding.. then we **must** explain why need to use these and what is the logic of using them.. as in my answer the logic of the using **using block**..

if helpers need that ones always need to ask them then ones don't need to help as a free.. they can create a site as expert-exchange.com and earn money from questions ;)

Comment: ???????? he's trying to save a dictionary in a table and doesn't know how. That's the question!

Comment: Yes.. He is trying to save a dict values in a table.. and the best solution is how he can understand easily and do it correctly as soon as possible..

in your answer which before edited your fault is that : in loop you wrote dict.key.. with this its retrieve all the keys in a collection and code waits only 1 key.. in that why your code gave error..

Comment: i'm tired of this conversation